# Construct the thicker topology such that the family $\{U_\lambda \}_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ is open.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ a space and $\{U_\lambda\}_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ a collection of subset of $X$. I want to construct the thicker topology $\mathcal T$ such that the $U_\lambda $ are open. Does it work as that : I set

$$\mathcal S=\left\{\bigcap_{\lambda \in \Gamma}U_\lambda \mid \Gamma\subset \Lambda, |\Gamma|<\infty \right\},$$
do we have 
$$\mathcal T =\left\{\bigcup_{U\in \mathcal G}U\mid \mathcal G\subset \mathcal S\right\}\ \ ?$$

I checked that $\mathcal T$ is stable by finite intersection, but is $\mathcal T$ the thicker topology ?

Comment: Thicker than what? The topology you constructed is definitely the smallest topology in which all $U_{\lambda}$ are open. Unless $U_{\lambda}$ do not cover $X$ in which case you have to add $X$ to the topology.

Comment: $\{X\}\cup \mathcal T$  is a topology on $X$.  If $\mathcal V$ is a topology on $X$ and  $\mathcal V\supset  \{U_{\lambda}\}_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ then $\mathcal V\supset \{X\} \cup \mathcal T.$......In English, if $T_1$ and $T_2$ are topologies on $X$ we say $T_1$ is stronger than $T_2$ ( and equivalently, that $T_2 $is weaker than $T_1$)  to mean that $T_1\supset T_2.$ This is standard usage, but may be confusing, because $T_1$ is both stronger and weaker than itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your construction is ok, you only need that the $U_\lambda$ cover $X.$ Given any collection $\mathcal{U}=\{U_\lambda\}_{\lambda \in \Lambda}$ of subsets of $X$ we can define a topology $\mathcal{T}$ for which $\mathcal{U}$ is a *subbasis*. This topology $\mathcal{T}$ is defined to be the collection of all unions of finite intersections of elements of $\mathcal{U},$ which is what you have. This topology equals the intersection of all topologies on $X$ that contain $\mathcal{U},$ and thus is the coarsest (smallest) topology on $X$ that contains $\mathcal{U}.$